# Using try statement, but giving me syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, try-catch, try-except

Simple problem. I need to get the user to input a number, and then convert the string into an integer using try/except.

I've done things similar to this before. In fact I've done much more complicated things before, which is why I'm so confused as to why my code isn't working.

```
userNum = input('enter a number: ')
try:
    num = int(userNum)
```

For some reason this causes a syntax error.
The error statement reads:

```
Syntax Error:     num = int(userNum): <string>, line 3, pos 23
```

Can anyone tell me why this would cause a problem and how I could fix it? I'm so confused.

Comment: *Pretty sure my code is right* - The fact that compiler is telling you there is a syntax error in your code should be a strong hint that your code is **not** right.

Comment: @SergeyA pretty pretty, means pretty, so, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try needs to have at least one of the 
except or finally expressions followed as in:

```
userNum = input('enter a number: ')
try:
    num = int(userNum)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: You can omit an `except` clause if you provide a `finally` clause.

Answer (score 2):

you can either use finally if you want something always happen, if you want something happen on error, use except:

```
userNum = input('enter a number: ')
try:
    num = int(userNum)
finally:
    print("something")
```

or:

```
userNum = input('enter a number: ')
try:
    num = int(userNum)
except Exception:
  print("exception something")
finally:
    print("something")
```

or:

```
userNum = input('enter a number: ')
try:
    num = int(userNum)
except Exception:
    print("exception something")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [syntax of a `try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#try), you can see that at least one `except` part *or* a `finally` part is obligatory.

Working code with except:

```python
userNum = input('enter a number: ')
try:
    num = int(userNum)
except:
    print("you didn't enter a number")
print(num)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYw7DoAgEER7TrGhQWo7Eq/gHfxsogULWXcTOT1qoHG6yXszuciRaKxVL@RZI0xwUlYZHJIgwwKkcUUO4LwRLsHAG@qiDH3mDd4bZmk484dsSQr7uZMT@J9Zb5ryVl/r@AA)